# Active Record: Parent Model w/ Multiple Child Model Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to understand the best way to model some data for a rails app using active record.

**Stack**
Rails 4.1.0.beta1 & Ruby 2.0 & Postgres

Here is my scenario. I have 3 "Content Types" of Article, Video and Graphic. My goal is to be able to ask Active Record for all the Contents I have published and that are the newest ones in the Database. Such as give me the last 10 Content Items no matter what 'type' to display in an efficient way.

**Here is my initial thoughts:**
Content - has_many: articles, videos, graphics 
          published_date:datetime
Article - belongs_to: content
Video - belongs_to: content
Graphic - belongs_to: content

I am guessing its something like this but I am not sure if this is the most efficient way. All Articles, Videos and Graphics would inherit attributes from the Content model. But each Article, Video and Graphic would have their own attributes.

What is the best way to organize this data for speed and growth if a new Content Type is introduced? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly following the model relationships you laid out in your "Here is my initial thoughts":

If you were to add a new Content Type down the road I believe it should be as simple as adding the correct has_many and belongs_to tags in the model headers. Your Content model could have as many has_many's as you wanted aka as many content types as you want.

To retrieve the newest 10 content items you could do a join on the three content type tables that match the content id grabbing the 10 newest items in each table, then sort that in reverse chronological order and grab the first 10 items.

Comment: Ok just wasn't sure if this was the smartest way. But thanks for the answer none the less. :)